# Ionic5 Capacitor AppRate does not install

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to include [AppRate](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-rate) in my app following the instructions

```
npm install cordova-plugin-apprate
npm install @ionic-native/app-rate
ionic cap sync
```

but I get

```
⚡️  [warn] - Native: tried calling AppRate.preferences, but the AppRate plugin is not installed.
⚡️  [warn] - Install the AppRate plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-apprate'
```

when calling AppRate.

The package is in the iOS project path

```
ll ios/capacitor-cordova-ios-plugins/sources/CordovaPluginApprate/
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   1.2K Jun 27 09:00 CDVAppRate.h
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff   3.8K Jun 27 09:00 CDVAppRate.m
```

Usually the nearly identical instructions how to install native plugins would work. This is the first that they are

Here's how I call it in my code

```
import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate/ngx';
...
providers: [AppRate],
...

    showAppRate(){
      this.appRate.preferences.storeAppURL = {
        ios: 'ID',
        android: 'LINK'
      };

      this.appRate.promptForRating(true);
    }
```

Not doing anything different...
Is it missing in the build process somehow? How could I check that?

Comment: try to use AppRate.setPreferences instead of AppRate.preferences

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. The help page needs an update